# WordPress database Path or URL error

Tags: database, wordpress, migrate

I tried to migrate the WP database using the Migrate DB plugin but I put the wrong URL or path name and I get the wrong URL path name like: http://med-seed.com/med-seed.com/med-seed.com/question/what-is-the-new-weight-loss-surgery-techniques-4/

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: How do I correct the the url from the db

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it,

1. export your database
2. save it on your PC
3. go to PHP MyAdmin on your new host, import your dataBase and thats it.

Should take you less then 10 mins.